# Possible Issues With BizTalk Host

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

In our BizTalk environment, we have specific hosts for processing, receiving and sending.  A few days ago, we saw the following information message in the event log.

```
The following BizTalk host instance has initialized successfully. 

BizTalk host name: SendHost
Windows service name: BTSSvc$SendHost
```

This message started happening at 1:04:41 AM and shows up about every minute until 10:01:05 PM that night.  It also appears that each time the host as initialized, everything that would have been queued to send would start sending.  So each minute, the same data appears to attempt to send - as there is nearly an equal number of Error messages in the Event Log for all our various interfaces.

I'm wondering what would cause the Send Host to reinitialize itself every minute, and if it happens again, how to find out what's causing it.  Has anyone seen this type of behavior before?  If so, how did you resolve it?

** EDIT **

At 1:00:24 AM, the following error was logged in the Application Log

```
Application: BTSNTSvc.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Runtime.CallbackException
Stack:
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean)
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean, System.Exception)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionStream+IOAsyncResult.OnAsyncIOComplete(System.Object)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.FinishRead()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.OnReceiveAsync(System.Object, System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.OnReceiveAsyncCompleted(System.Object, System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs)
   at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.OnCompleted(System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs)
   at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.FinishOperationSuccess(System.Net.Sockets.SocketError, Int32, System.Net.Sockets.SocketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.CompletionPortCallback(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)
   at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)
```

And then at 1:00:24 AM the following error is logged

```
Faulting application name: BTSNTSvc.exe, version: 3.11.158.0, time stamp: 0x538aea40
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.2.9200.16864, time stamp: 0x531d2be6
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x00010f22
Faulting process id: 0x1f0c
Faulting application start time: 0x01d0603d63ff5bbe
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft BizTalk Server 2013\BTSNTSvc.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: fd2a4f01-d2c4-11e4-9411-005056b5474a
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Then at 1:03:39 AM the following Information event was logged:

```
Fault bucket , type 0
Event Name: CLR20r3
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: btsntsvc.exe
P2: 3.11.158.0
P3: 538aea40
P4: System.ServiceModel
P5: 4.0.30319.34230
P6: 53be5c02
P7: c6
P8: 152
P9: I0SHPZEWVQV4P1UJY40X15MQTHF34RR5
P10: 

Attached files:
C:\Users\svc_BTSHost\AppData\Local\Temp\WER5EA7.tmp.appcompat.txt
C:\Users\svc_BTSHost\AppData\Local\Temp\WERA73C.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
C:\Users\svc_BTSHost\AppData\Local\Temp\WERA75C.tmp.hdmp
C:\Users\svc_BTSHost\AppData\Local\Temp\WER3885.tmp.mdmp

These files may be available here:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue   \AppCrash_btsntsvc.exe_8592b3518472b55b77d4f91bb554882409312a0_cab_3c0d3d42

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: fd2a4f01-d2c4-11e4-9411-005056b5474a
Report Status: 4
```

The next event logged was at 1:04:41 AM - the Host initializing successfully.

The above two error events and information event occur just before the SendHost is initialized event for the next 21 hours

Comment: There's no other messages in the event log before that?

Comment: I WAS looking in a special view for the keyword "BizTalk", but looking in the Application Log, I can see that BTSNTSVC.exe was crashing just before.

At 1:00:13 AM, the following error shows up:
`Application: BTSNTSvc.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Runtime.CallbackException`

Comment: Can you add the full text of the exception there?  Chances are googling that text (especially if there's an ID or HRESULT) will set your issue straight.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5036d687-ebff-4828-a190-5ead362b8305/biztalk-2013-r2-wccustom-adapter-sapbinding-unhandeld-exception-on-failure-tests?forum=biztalkr2adapters

Comment: The comment field was too short to add all the addition info, see my EDIT to see the detailed events.  I was looking at a custom event log view for "BizTalk", and not looking at the Application view (sidebar: expanding the scope of our BizTalk view now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your host instance is crashing due to an unhandled exception occurring in the adapter you're using.  This is very likely due to some configuration error in your adapter, or response from the server that BizTalk isn't expecting.  It also seems like it's a bug in the adapter.

See [BizTalk 2013 R2 - WC-Custom Adapter SAP-Binding: Unhandeld (sic) exception on failure tests](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5036d687-ebff-4828-a190-5ead362b8305/biztalk-2013-r2-wccustom-adapter-sapbinding-unhandeld-exception-on-failure-tests?forum=biztalkr2adapters) for someone having similar issues with sapBinding.

Comment: Based on the answers in the thread you linked, we'll have to wait until the next CU to potentially see a fix.  Thanks for the response, marking as resolved.

Comment: @djm61 CU4 is out and it has multiple fixes for the WCF-Sap adapter.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf yeah, I saw that.  We are [unfortunately] a couple of CU's behind.  And we haven't seen this issue since I marked the answer as completed.

Comment: Did CU4 fix your issue?  If so I'll update the answer (or you can and I'll approve the edit)

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug agreed by microsoft and given fix in CU5 but though it is installed still issue comes.My Finding is by default HTTP adapter timeout is set to 0, after increasing the timeout duration issue got resolved.